# Could someone explain these Apache rewrite rules?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am taking an online course in which the instructor implements a couple of Apache rewrite rules - something that I have not come across before, and which the instructor fails to explain in any detail.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I understand that the rules are there to rewrite the URL, making it seem like `public/` is not part of it. However, I am after a more detailed explanation.

My question is essentially: Could someone explain how these rewrite rules turn something like `application/public/index` into just `application/index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

1. This is a hack in order to be able to use a modern framework or application in a cheap or lousy hosting provider that does not allow to have files outside the public directory tree. It often needs to be complemented with some additional settings to prevent private stuff from being downloaded.
2. Apache web server has [comprehensive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/) where all the directives are explained. For some reason, many developers are reluctant to check this documentation.

Now, from top to botton:

- **[<IfModule>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#ifmodule) mod_rewrite.c>** executes the configuration wrapped inside if and only if the server has the URL-rewriting module (mod_rewrite) installed and enabled. It prevents the site from crashing when the module is not available (of course, if the site does need the module it only means that it'll fail in some other way).
- **[RewriteEngine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) On** enables URL-rewriting features provided by the module (having the module available doesn't mean it's turned on).
- [**RewriteRule**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is the heart of it all:

  > `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]`

  When current URL follows a given **pattern** then it will be transformed using **Substitution**.

  Flag `last|L` means *Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules*. Then, rewriting starts again with the new URL, until there aren't more rules that apply.

  `(.*)` is a regular expression that means "match any character that appears zero or more times and store it as "group 1". The `$1` in `public/$1` means "insert group 1 here".

So, in short, it hides the "public" directory si requests to `http://example.com/foo.jpg` what would normally be mapped to `/var/www/htdocs/foo.jpg` get mapped to `/var/www/htdocs/public/foo.jpg`.

Comment: Thank you, Álvaro, for your thorough explanation! Although, could you perhaps also explain why the first rewrite rule matches both **start of line**, as well as **end of line** with `^$`. Why is this necessary?

Comment: @MihkelPajunen Honestly, I don't know and I don't think I'll ever do. The "root" directory tends to be special and need particular rules. `mod_rewrite` is a very complex tool and it also has to interact with all other Apache features.